# Reorder composite primary key in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I want to use inheritance when defining my sqlalchemy tables.

```
class DatetimeBase(object):
    inserted = Column(DateTime, primary_key=True)

class OtherTable(DeclarativeBase, DatetimeBase):
    __tablename__ = 'other_table'

    blah = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    other_column = Column(Text)
```

Now I have a composite primary key on `other_table`, namely `(inserted, blah)`. However, for efficiency of queries (assuming I'm looking for the latest blah, etc.), it would be better if the timestamp came after the integer, `(blah, inserted)`. Is there some fancy way to reorder the primary key?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, using [`PrimaryKeyConstraint`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/constraints.html#sqlalchemy.schema.PrimaryKeyConstraint):

```
class OtherTable(DeclarativeBase, DatetimeBase):
    __tablename__ = 'other_table'

    blah = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    other_column = Column(Text)

    __table_args__ = (PrimaryKeyConstraint("blah", "inserted"),)
```

Comment: I had seen the existence of PrimarKeyConstraint, but I didn't know what to do with it. I didn't know you could use __table_args__ in that manner. Thanks.